# animation button moving in wheel like igun pro application for first screen iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, cocos2d-iphone

I am newbie I stuck on one problem i want to make animation which have buttons and moving up and down as like wheel moving.You can see the application "iGun Pro" the same animation i want to make but i am not getting how to make this it's done in core animation or used open GL for the moving buttons.I am not interested now they given animation on text.So please help me if also try to give code or some reference example so i can understand batter.I am not getting how i will search on the web for this animation .Any help appreciated Thank You.

I am very sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Here is an iGun Pro video review http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aKFeHtTX23k
I really do not see what kind of menu you are talking about.

Comment: Thank For the reply. I am talking the menu which  start of the application like buttons with images of guns which move in circle as like wheel moving for the selection gun.http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/igun-pro-lite-the-original/id308537544?mt=8

Comment: The animation which shows like cover flow but but cover flow is not smooth as whatever they used in this application.I am just giving you the example of cover flow to get the idea i am talking about which menu. Thank You @Joris Mans

Comment: I am not entirely sure but is [this](http://pocketworx.com/?p=167) what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this. The code is pasted here for moving a wheel up and down. 
You can use the same logic to move the button too. 
[Link is here.](http://kmdarshan.wordpress.com/2012/11/12/animating-a-wheel-in-ios-moving-it-or-degrees-in-a-circle/)